# Android: Using make with external java libraries

Tags: android

I have split out common components into libraries using Eclipse.  Everything works great.  I have resources/etc in the library.  However, I need to make the same functionality work with using make instead of Eclipse.  I need the libraries to recompile every time the APK is made.

Completely a noob question, but everything I am finding deals with making it work in Eclipse or creating a Jar file and inserting it into the project.

Thanks - Keith

Answer (score 0):

create jar file:

You could use the `Export->Java->Runnable` Jar to create a jar that includes its dependencies

check this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html), And this similar type [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871378/create-java-library-file)

Comment: Thanks for answering me so quickly!  But I have one issue with that.

If I make a jar file then the resources (specifically the R file) will not be right and you will not be able to inflate views that are contained in the library.

Comment: resource file will be there and you can able to inflate views also..!!you have to check ..i have never been to this sort of problem!!!!