# patch support library using Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I've moved my project to Android Studio a month ago, and I'm glad I did, despite the need to switch to a new (and more powerful) build system (gradle). One thing I'd have known in Eclipse, but I can't figure out how to achieve now, is patching the support library. I know that it does not sound like a good practice, but a couple of code lines are driving me crazy, and the solution would be to simply modify it to solve my problem.
I've tried to modify the code in the sdk's ".\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support" directory, but that does not seem to affect the code that is really used for compilation.
Any idea about how to achieve this ?

**Edit:**

I tried to create a module "SupportLibraryV4" in my project, and this is what gradle tells me when I try to build it :

```
Error Code:
    1
Output:

    trouble processing "java/android/support/v4/R$anim.class":

    Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
    when not building a core library.

    This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
    in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
    Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
    core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
    going on.

    However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
    namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
    from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
    assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
    compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
    It is also often of questionable legality.

    If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
    appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
    distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
    the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.

    If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
    building an application, then be forewarned that your application
    will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
    prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
    application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
    system. You will be to blame for this problem.

    If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
    core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
    repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
    your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
    conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
    you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
    that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
    lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.

    1 error; aborting
```

impressive !

Comment: you have to import support library project(from: "ANDROIDSDKPATH\extras\android\support\v4\src")  as module to your project and replace `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'` with `compile project(":NameOfSupportModule")` in build.gradle of your "main" module

Comment: thx Selvin =) can you put your answer as an answer (not a comment) ? this way I can "validate" it or comment it... btw, I have a problem importing the library build.gradle:
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-rc-3-bin.zip'.
Build file 'C:\Users\zgui\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\android\support\v4\src\build.gradle' line: 21
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'src'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'src'.
Could not find method getAndroidPrebuilt() for arguments [5] on root project 'src'.

Comment: i did some tests and, hmmm, this is not valid answer ...

Comment: As of Android Studio 0.3.7 and version 0.6.x of the Gradle plugin, you have to use Gradle 1.8; 1.9 isn't compatible. If you use the Gradle wrapper it should choose the correct version of Gradle automatically. If you're having other errors, please edit your post with the full details.

Answer (score 3):

Android sdk doesn't have all required files for building support library.
You need to checkout additional repositories from https://android.googlesource.com:

- platform/frameworks/support
- platform/prebuilts/gradle-plugin
- platform/prebuilts/maven_repo/android
- platform/prebuilts/sdk
- platform/prebuilts/tools

Please, keep the directory structure as in android repository.

Now you could change any code in support library. If you need to change support library for api v.4 do it in "platform\frameworks\support\v4". For building patched version of support library use gradle with next command:

```
platform\frameworks\support\v4\gradle clean jar
```

Resulted jar could be found in "platform\out\host\gradle\frameworks\support\v4\libs\". Put it to the libs folder of your project and add in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

Updated answer 2016 for Linux and OS X using the bundled gradle wrapper instead of the system's gradle installation:

Checkout the following repositories from https://android.googlesource.com and keep the directory structure:

- platform/frameworks/support
- platform/prebuilts/gradle-plugin
- platform/prebuilts/maven_repo/android
- platform/prebuilts/sdk
- platform/prebuilts/tools
- platform/tools/external/gradle

**Modify files in the library:**

- Change files in `platform/frameworks/support/`

**Build AAR**

- `cd platform/frameworks/support`
- `./gradlew jarRelease`
- The resulting .aar is in `platform/out/host/gradle/frameworks/support/<module>/build/outputs/aar/`

**Add to project**

- Create a `libs/` folder next to your app's build.gradle
- Add libs folder to build.gradle: `repositories{ flatDir{ dirs 'libs' } }`
- Copy the .aar file to `libs/`
- Add aar to your dependencies section in build.gradle, e.g.: `dependencies { compile(name:'my_custom_supportlib_module', ext:'aar') }`

**Module already in project**

When you patches a support library module that other modules depend on, you'll have it twice in the build causing errors. This can be avoided by excluding the original dependency.

If you for example patch `recyclerview-v7` and add

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'recyclerview-v7-release', ext:'aar')
}
```

you have to exclude the dependency like this. Change

```
compile "com.android.support:design:24.2.1"
```

to

```
compile("com.android.support:design:24.2.1") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
}
```

for all modules that depend on the patched module.

Answer (score 0):

Patch the SupportLib and add it manually as a jar:

- Put the SupportLib jar into the libs folder
- Right click it and hit 'Add as library'
- Ensure that compile files('libs/supportlib.jar') is in your build.gradle file
- Do a clean build

Disclaimer: [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: thanks, but my main problem is actually to build the library, in Android Studio. I may create an Eclipse project especially for that if I have no other choice though...

Comment: Just use commandline? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871378/create-java-library-file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Ilya Tretyakov's answer only works for parts of the support library that don't have resources because they can't be put into a `.jar`.

The correct way to build for example the design-support-library is as follows:

checkout these repos from https://android.googlesource.com and keep the file structure:

- platform/frameworks/support
- platform/prebuilts/gradle-plugin
- platform/prebuilts/maven_repo/android
- platform/prebuilts/sdk
- platform/prebuilts/tools

navigate to platform/frameworks/support/design and edit whatever file you want. Now rebuild everything with `gradle clean assembleRelease`

you can find the resulting library file `support-design-release.aar` in `platform/out/host/gradle/frameworks/support/support-design/build/outputs/aar`

create an `app/libs` folder in your project and edit the `app/build.gradle`:

```
repositories{
   flatDir{
      dirs 'libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile(name:'support-design-release.aar', ext:'aar')
}
```

do a clean rebuild of your project and everything will work as intended