# Use java library command line

Tags: java, sublimetext2

I want to use [this](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning) library in my Java project which I run build with sublime text `ctrl+b` and then `java` from command line. There are no instruction on how to include this in my project and can't find any simple instructions while searching.

How do I use this library? I'm on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of

1. Download source code and [build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871378/create-java-library-file) it as jar package. Add this jar file to your project classpath.
2. Download source code and add all source files as your project source.

Answer (score 0):

Best is to do something clean and durable :

1. [install maven (see this article, it takes only 5 minutes!)](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)
2. init a project .pom file
3. add the lib  dependency , [see librairy doc](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning/blob/master/wiki/Maven_Dependency.md)

   uk.com.robust-it
           cloning
           1.9.2
4. build using  maven command  :

   maven clean install
5. enjoy